# Casting a void ** return

Tags: c, visual-studio, pointers, casting

We all know that one shouldn't cast the `void *` return of `malloc`/`calloc`, but what of similar functions that return `void **`? I have the following function:

```c
void **calloc_2d(const size_t ptr_count, const size_t size_buffers, const size_t size_elem)
{
    void **array = calloc(ptr_count, sizeof(void *));
    for (size_t i=0; i < ptr_count; i++)
        array[i] = calloc(size_buffers, size_elem);
    return array;
}
```

And I may call it this way:

```c
char **string_array = calloc_2d(5, 32, sizeof(char));
```

But unlike with regular `calloc` here Visual Studio tells me

> Warning C4133 '=': incompatible types - from 'void **' to 'char **'

It sounds like I'm expected to cast it, why? And is there any way to avoid casting for every call to this function?

Comment: @GSerg It does, thank you, somehow it didn't turn up in my search. I guess that makes my question a duplicate.